# Multi apps kiosk mode in Android?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

Currently, I got stuck in a scenario in which I create a demo which is single kiosk app. I want to create an app which allows selected apps to show in the list/grid which are accessible from the app only, other then that are not. The kiosk app stays as a home default. I have checked for different paid platforms but is it possible to create or work with it manually.
Any help will be appreciable.